# Julia get location and variable name from UndefVarError

Tags: error-handling, julia

How can I get an undefined variable name and its location?
For example, in the code below

```
x = a +1
```

The output is:

```
UndefVarError: `a` not defined

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ In[1]:1
```

How do I get out from "Stacktrace" with the variable name and its location (row,column)? **What I would need is a tupel object ("a",1,5)**

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
err = try
    x = a + 1
catch
    (e, bt) = first(current_exceptions())
    var = e.var
    st = stacktrace(bt)
    line = st[1].line
    (var, line)
end
print(err)  # (a, 2)
```

## Explanation

In order to get the undefined symbol and the line it appeared on, you need to look in a few different different places:

## Catching the exception

The [`UndefVarError`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Core.UndefVarError) struct has a property `var::Symbol` naming the symbol that is undefined. If you want your program to report the name of the undefined variable, you need to access that exception. One way to do that is to wrap your code in a [`try ... catch`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/control-flow/#The-try/catch-statement) block, like so:

```
err = try
    x = a + 1
catch e
    e.var
end
print(err)  # a
```

If you need the symbol as a string, convert it with `string(e.var)`.

## Digging through the stack trace

The current stack trace is always available by calling [`stacktrace()`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/stacktraces/#Base.StackTraces.stacktrace), which returns a `Vector{StackTraces.StackFrame}`. Each of these [`StackFrame`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/stacktraces/#Base.StackTraces.StackFrame) objects has a `line` property, so if you know that an `UndefVarError` has been thrown, you can get the line where the exception was thrown.

Unfortunately, calling `stacktrace()` with no arguments will produce the stack trace at the line where `stacktrace()` was called, not where the exception was thrown. This example may help:

```
try
    x = a + 1           # this is line 2, where the error happens
catch
    st = stacktrace()   # this is line 4
    println(st[1].line) # prints 4, not 2
end
```

To get the line where the exception was thrown, you need to access the [backtrace](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/stacktraces/#Comparison-with-%5Bbacktrace%5D(@ref)) of the current exception, and you can do that with [`current_exceptions()`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/stacktraces/#Exception-stacks-and-%5Bcurrent_exceptions%5D(@ref)). This is a function that returns an iterator of pairs of exceptions and backtraces--with it, you can iterate through stacks of exceptions, allowing you to investigate not only where an initial investigation was thrown, but also cases where your exception handling code might have thrown an exception. The first iteration value returned from `current_exceptions()` is always the most recent exception thrown, so you just need to convert the first backtrace into a `StackFrame` object, then access the line where the exception was thrown:

```
err = try
    x = a + 1
catch
    (e, bt) = first(current_exceptions())
    var = e.var
    st = stacktrace(bt)
    line = st[1].line
    (var, line)
end
print(err)  # (a, 2)
```

But that might be as far as you can go.

## Parsing the column number

Unfortunately, there is no good way to figure out what column contains the offending undefined symbol. Julia does not save the code as written in the `StackFrame`, only a representation of the [AST](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/devdocs/ast/) that Julia parsed in the `linfo` property. The AST does not retain the exact character layout of the original code, so you cannot back out what column in a line caused the error.

Here is an example of what the `linfo` property of the `StackFrame` can tell you about this toy code:

```
julia> ci = try
           x = a + 1
       catch
           (_, bt) = first(current_exceptions())
           st = first(stacktrace(bt))
           st.linfo
       end
CodeInfo(
    @ REPL[1]:1 within `top-level scope`
1 ─ %1  = $(Expr(:enter, #4))
    @ REPL[1]:2 within `top-level scope`
2 ─ %2  = a + 1
│         x = %2
│         @_5 = %2
└──       $(Expr(:leave, 1))
3 ─       goto #6
4 ┄       $(Expr(:leave, 1))
    @ REPL[1]:4 within `top-level scope`
5 ─ %8  = current_exceptions()
│   %9  = first(%8)
│   %10 = Base.indexed_iterate(%9, 1)     
│         Core.getfield(%10, 1)
│         @_2 = Core.getfield(%10, 2)     
│   %13 = Base.indexed_iterate(%9, 2, @_2)
│         bt = Core.getfield(%13, 1)
│   @ REPL[1]:5 within `top-level scope`
│   %15 = stacktrace(bt)
│         st = first(%15)
│   @ REPL[1]:6 within `top-level scope`
│         @_5 = Base.getproperty(st, :linfo)
└──       $(Expr(:pop_exception, :(%1)))
6 ┄ %19 = @_5
│   %20 = Core.get_binding_type(Main, :ci)
│   %21 = Base.convert(%20, %19)
│   %22 = Core.typeassert(%21, %20)
│         ci = %22
└──       return %19
)
```

You can see in the block starting with `2 ─ %2` what the AST representation of `x = a + 1` looks like, but from that, you can't tell that the `a` appeared as the 9th character in the line.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. It is very helpful. So, we can get the variable name and the line, but not a column. OK, not bad.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not clear to me why you would want that, there are two different things you could look into:

- Exception Handling: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/control-flow/#Exception-Handling This will allow you to deal with the exceptions and errors that occur and might be the cleanest and easiest way. For some of these exceptions you can also access additional information. Like for the `UndefVarError` you'll get the variable as a symbol as `e.var` (if `e` is an instance of the error). Use the `try`/`catch` syntax to get the exception and the name of the variable.
- Stacktrace: You actually look into the stacktrace as a string itself like explained here https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/stacktraces/#Error-handling